# Error debugging using Code Composer Studio

Tags: c, texas-instruments, code-composer

I use DRV8301-RM46-KIT to control my induction motor. Previously, I had successfully debugged the existing example program code. But now, I cant. The following is a description of the error.

```
CortexR4: GEL Output:   Memory Map Setup for Flash @ Address 0x0Dap: Error: (Error -242 @ 0x0) A router subpath could not be accessed. The board configuration file is probably incorrect. (Emulation package 9.13.0.00201) 
CortexR4: Error: (Error -1170 @ 0x0) Unable to access the DAP. Reset the device, and retry the operation. If error persists, confirm configuration, power-cycle the board, and/or try more reliable JTAG settings (e.g. lower TCLK). (Emulation package 9.13.0.00201) 
CortexR4: Unable to determine target status after 20 attempts
CortexR4: Failed to remove the debug state from the target before disconnecting.  There may still be breakpoint op-codes embedded in program memory.  It is recommended that you reset the emulator before you connect and reload your program before you continue debugging
```

As far as I remember, this error occurred after I accidentally set an expression as a breakpoint. However, when I delete the breakpoint, I can never debug the program code into the device, even by using the print "Hello World" code. I've tried changing the device I use to debug program code, but the results are the same.

Please someone who understands this problem, this is my fourth day with an unresolved problem:((

I have tried various ways, starting from changing my debug rules, doing experiments on Texas Instrument forums, reading Texas Instrument documentation and trying to do something that might solve my problem, but all failed to solve the problem.

When I tried to solve the problem, I suspected that in the device I was using, there was program code running. So I have to stop this program code. But again, this is just an assumption. I don't really know what causes it.

I also suspect that the solution to my problem has been discussed here https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/troubleshooting-data_verification_errors.html

But, there is something I cant do, like **"erase flash"** in "Diagnosing Flash Problems" section.

Thank you for your help:'), I really appreciate it.